# ObjectListView with property having parameter

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

I have a class with property like this :

```
public readonly class human(awake as boolean) as string
   get
      return if(awake, me.blob & "yes", me.blob & "no")
   end get
end class
```

Ok this is a dummy example, but i have to make a class with parameter to work with ObjectListView (not listview). Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I am having trouble following, what is it exactly you are trying to do? It seems like you are saying the `ObjectListView` is requiring a constructor of some kind. Is that right?

Comment: How is the above code relevant to ObjectListView?

Comment: The OLV has no specific requirements regarding the constructor signature, since it is never instantiating model objects on its own (AFAIK). You should give an example of what exactly you are trying to achieve.